# How to get a LOW framerate when an iframe is in the viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I need to get a **LOW** framerate when a cross-domain `iframe` is scrolled into the viewport. This is needed because I want to use `requestAnimationFrame()` to understand the position of it, from within the cross-domain `iframe`. For example,

```
var last_time = 0;
var lst_diff = [];
var avg = 0;

function frame_check(current_time){
    var diff = current_time - last_time;
    last_time = current_time;

    if (lst_diff.length > 5){
        lst_diff.shift();
    }
    lst_diff.push(diff);

    var sum = 0;
    lst_diff.forEach(function(val){
       sum += val;
    });
    avg = sum / lst_diff.length;

    // if (avg < some threshold )
    // indicates it is in the viewport
    // do something

    requestAnimationFrame(frame_check);
}
requestAnimationFrame(frame_check);
```

When it is in the viewport, what can I do in the `iframe` to make it efficient, in terms of taking little space and drops the framerate significantly? I tried to

- Draw something in the `canvas` but the browser keeps doing it even out of the viewport;
- Apply heavy CSS styles like multiple `text-shadow` and change the position of the `div` but it didn't work well. I cannot even tell if the framerate was dropping.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do, but maybe you could check the iframe position very frequently with a `setInterval(frame_check,1000/60)` (60 check by seconds). Dropping the framerate doesn't sound like a solution to me, but maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: Getting the position of a cross-domain iframe (within it) is quite impossible. I'll make it clear in the question.

Comment: do you have any access to the page contained by the iframe ?

Comment: No. Otherwise I can use `postMessage`

Comment: That's what I was thinking. But I still don't get what you are trying to do.

Comment: Quite simple actually: I want to tell if an `iframe` is in the viewport by observing the framerate. But the 'reason' is not really a question here.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand that you were doing this FROM the iframe, I never did that but you can actually access the parent window from an iframe using `window.parent` then get the iframe element from the parent and get its current offset and the parent's scroll. I don't think cross-domain is a problem when you are in the iframe... I'll try it later, so much work this morning...

Comment: No you cannot access the `parent` from a cross-domain iframe.

Comment: then you got... tears!

Comment: maybe you can draw a [mandelbrot set using css](http://codepen.io/pixelass/pen/HbnCv) and 100000 iterations and points but it's a bit overkill :D

Comment: It could work but not efficient. The CSS is way too big (usually in MB).

Comment: what ever the method you will use, it will never work, because it will be a hack and there will be thousands of circumstances it will not. Even if you achieved this miracle, there will be some case where your code would be so heavy that the browser will run out of memory and become unusable, or the computer being so fast that your code could not even notice the framerate drop.

Comment: try using a same-domain webserver as a proxy if you can, that would be an non-hacky solution

Comment: Calibration based on the performance. No need to achieve 100% as long as the result is statistically significant. It is interesting because it is challenging, eh? I won't bother to ask this question if I can get a same-domain proxy. I do thank you for directing me to a possible direction: heavy CSS like that Mandelbrot set.